# how to integrate Microsoft Bing Speech API text-speech functionality with MS Teams Application

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, text-to-speech, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to integrate Microsoft Bing speech api Text-Speech functionality with MS Teams application,based on some R n D I got the blog in-which has some sample code to do and below is code from sample:

```
     var audioBaseUri = new Uri("http://public_path_to_url_base/");
     var fileName = "audiofile";
     var ttsMedia = new MediaInfo
      {
        Uri = new Uri(audioBaseUri, fileName).ToString(),
        ResourceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
      };
    var ttsMediaPrompt = new MediaPrompt() { MediaInfo = ttsMedia, Loop = 1 };
    ICall call = this.Client.Calls()["*id of the call*"];
   await call.PlayPromptAsync(*A list of media prompts to play*).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

For audioBaseUri,I have hosted my text-speech output result on ngrok to get public path url base.
Issue is with is Call.PlayPromptAsync method,I tried installing NuGet-package **Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls** but still I am not able to get this.Client.calls here so I tried to replace this line of code as below:

```
 ICall call = Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Client.Calls()["*id of the call*"];
```

> Above line of code is giving me error as the type or namespace name 'Calls' does not exist in the namespace **Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls**(are you missing an assembly reference?)

If anyone has suggestions on how to proceed with and also give some inputs on how to access the audio settings of MS Teams Application as its required to send text-speech from client application to on-going Call on MS Teams Application would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have done it with azure bot integration with teams, however may I know how you are trying to integrated with?

Comment: I am trying to integrate WPF application which has the bing TTS api result with on-going call on MS teams application.Is it possible to share some sample code how you have integrated azure bot with teams?

Comment: Hi,@Md Farid Uddin Kiron I am looking forward for help.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have worked with Bing search on bot not text to speech. But separately worked with text to speech which not in teams that's why didn't post.

Comment: Thanks @Md Farid Uddin Kiron. 1.Is there any way to integrate TTS with Teams.2.On some R n D I found call: playPrompt feature of Microsoft Graph API will help us to play a prompt in the call,if you can help me with sample code would me much helpful